# Deleted Desktop.ini file keeps returning

Tags: windows-10, desktop.ini

A nearly empty directory keeps re-appearing on my D drive.  It seems like a Desktop.ini file keeps being re-created. The "stuff" I want to delete is:

d:\ManualCopy\HomePC\2019-06-04\UserRobert\Music\Desktop.ini

I delete "from the left" (D:\ManualCopy) or "from the right" (Desktop.ini and each directory) but the next time I log to the drive the file and directories are back.

It seems "Music" is some type of special directory.  How do I delete this nearly empty copy of it?

I even did a full (hour long) format of D.  It still came back.  Is it in a registry?

Thanks

Comment: [What is the Windows desktop.ini file and can I delete it?](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001060.htm)

Comment: I'm trying to delete a MANUAL COPY of files which, unfortunately, included a Desktop.ini.  I want to delete the unneeded copy of the file I made, but it keeps on re-appearing.

Comment: Every time you look at a file using Windows Explorer/File Explorer, it will re-generate the desktop.ini file to reflect the information regarding how it appears in the Explorer display. It doesn't matter where the files are or how they got there.

Comment: So if you accidentally copy a directory containing a Desktop.ini file you can NEVER delete the copy????

Comment: So, it reads like you want to get rid of the `desktop ini` file and it keeps coming back, but auto-generating `desktop.ini` files is normal behavior for windwos and cannot be disabled. HOWEVER, it seems like you are really saying that the whole directory keeps being regenerated?

Comment: This is a COPY of files from my C: drive. One of those directories copied contained a Desktop.ini file.  I deleted the manually copied directories, but the Desktop.ini keeps being re-generated - six directories deep. I re-formatted the disk and the six empty nested directories were re-created with a Desktop.ini in the deepest one.

Comment: This was a manual copy of the "my music" folder?

Comment: @RobertFarley - It is perfectly normal for a Desktop.ini to be generated when you view a folder within File Explorer.  **The generation of this file cannot be disabled.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder & its desktop.ini file are being recreated because it is designated as a system folder (most likely, **Music**). As a system folder, its **Properties** dialog should have a **Location** tab that allows you to redifrect the folder to a different location. If that gives you issues, you can check the registry under:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

and (cautiously) edit the paths for the folders.

Comment: Is his secondary drive location actually a symbolic link to the system drive?

Comment: Close.  I used Regedit to correct the path for "My Music" to C:\Users\Robert\Music.  The deleted directories stayed away for about 5 minutes.  They are back now  :-(  Regedit's .\Exploer\Shell 
Folders is clean.  Who else might be re-adding the file?

Comment: Success!  Had to edit both "User Shell Folders" and "Shell Folders" to finally get it to work.   My guess is that one of the times I tried to copy, I inadvertently moved. I usually <Cntl>Z to undo, but this seems not to have fixed the Shell Folder designation.

Comment: You only had to edit **User Shell Folders**.